# Find the range of the Probability Mass Function in which $Y=X^2$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables

A probability mass function of a random variable $X$ has the range $R = \{ -1, 0, 1 \}$, where
$$f(-1)=0.2, \quad f(0)=0.6, \quad f(1)=0.2$$

Now we set $Y=X^2$, what will the range and probability mass function of $Y$ be?

How should I go about solving this?

Comment: Where do you get stuck?  What values can $Y$ take? What does $X$ have to be in order for $Y$ to be, say, $0$ and what is the probability that $X$ takes such values?

Comment: Thing is my attempt at solving it made no sense. If I'd square the range, the new one (Range-y) would only be between 0 and 1; is that even feasible? If I'd the plot out all the f(Y) it'd not sum up to 1. I'm simply not comprehending the process of this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The random variable $Y=X^2$ takes values in $\{(-1)^2,0^2,1^2\}=\{0,1\}$ (as you correctly say) with probabilities \begin{align}P(Y=1)&=P(X^2=1)=P(X=\pm1)\\[0.2cm]&=P(X=-1 \mbox{ or } X=1)\\[0.2cm]&=P(X=-1)+P(X=1)=0.4\end{align} and $$P(Y=0)=P(X^2=0)=P(X=0)=0.6$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I managed to figure it out just before you commented and got the same result as you. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Newman Nice that you did it by yourself... and you got also a confirmation ;)!